# r ggplot when two colors overlap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some codes to generate a plot,the only problem I have is there're many overlapping colors.

When two colors overlap, how do I specify the dominant color? 
For example, there're 4 black points when indicator = threshold. They are at 4 x-axis correspondingly. However, the black points at "Wire" and "ACH" scales do not show up because it is overlap with blue points. The black point at "RDFI" scale barely shows up. How can I make black as the dominant color when two colors overlap? Thanks ahead!

```
ggplot(df, aes(a-axis, y-axis), color=indicator)) + 
  geom_quasirandom(groupOnX=TRUE, na.rm = TRUE) +
  labs(title= 'chart', x='x-axis', y= 'y-axis') +
  scale_color_manual(name = 'indicator', values=c("#99ccff","#000000" ))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may not lie with what color is dominant.  You have selected colors that will show up often.  You may be losing the bottom of your Y axis.  The code you have in your example can not have possibly produced that plot it has errors.

Here is a simple example that show's one way to overcome your problem by simply overplottting the threshold points after you have plotted the beeswarm.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggbeeswarm)

distro <- data.frame(
'variable'=rep(c('runif','rnorm'),each=1000),
'value'=c(runif(2000, min=-3, max=3))
)

distro$indicator <- "NA"
distro[3,3] <- "Threshhold"
distro[163,3] <- "Threshhold"



ggplot2::ggplot(distro,aes(variable, value, color=indicator)) + 
  geom_quasirandom(groupOnX=TRUE, na.rm = TRUE, width=0.1) +
  scale_color_manual(name = 'indicator', values=c("#99ccff","#000000")) +
  geom_point(data = distro %>% filter(indicator == "Threshhold"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

for specify the dominant color you should use the function new_scale () and its aliases new_scale_color () and new_scale_fill ().

As an example, lets overlay some measurements over a contour map of topography using the beloed `volcano`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)
# Equivalent to melt(volcano)
topography <- expand.grid(x = 1:nrow(volcano),
                          y = 1:ncol(volcano))
topography$z <- c(volcano)

# point measurements of something at a few locations
set.seed(42)
measurements <- data.frame(x = runif(30, 1, 80),
                           y = runif(30, 1, 60),
                           thing = rnorm(30))
```

dominant point:

```
ggplot(mapping = aes(x, y)) +
  geom_contour(data = topography, aes(z = z, color = stat(level))) +
  # Color scale for topography
  scale_color_viridis_c(option = "D") +
  # geoms below will use another color scale
  new_scale_color() +
  geom_point(data = measurements, size = 3, aes(color = thing)) +
  # Color scale applied to geoms added after new_scale_color()
  scale_color_viridis_c(option = "A")
```

dominant contour:

```
ggplot(mapping = aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(data = measurements, size = 3, aes(color = thing)) +
  scale_color_viridis_c(option = "A")+
  new_scale_color() +
  geom_contour(data = topography, aes(z = z, color = stat(level))) +
  scale_color_viridis_c(option = "D")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I put your code into R and run it. But I'm relatively new to R. Can you please modify based on my code? I understand I didn't have replicable data so pseudocode is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You sort your data based on the color variable (your indicator).

Basically you want your black dots to be plotted last = on top of the other ones.

```
df$indicator <- sort(df$indicator, decreasing=T)

#Tidyverse solution

df <- df %>% arrange(desc(indicator))
```

Dependent on your levels you may have to reverse sort or not.

Then you just plot.

```
pd <- tibble(x=rnorm(1000), y=1, indicator=sample(c("A","B"), replace=T, size = 1000))
ggplot(pd, aes(x=x,y=y,color=indicator)) + geom_point()

pd <- pd %>% arrange(indicator)
ggplot(pd, aes(x=x,y=y,color=indicator)) + geom_point()

pd <- pd %>% arrange(desc(indicator))
ggplot(pd, aes(x=x,y=y,color=indicator)) + geom_point()
```